# Is this a copy of some sort of official erlang docs?

Tags: documentation, erlang, bitbucket

I came across this erlang doc repository on bitbucket.org through a google search, and I don't understand where it came from:

http://docs.bitbucket.org/erlang_otp/index.html

Is this just a copy of some official erlang docs? If so, where can I find the original index page on Erlang.com's site? This bitbucket page is a lot more comprehensive and easier to get a bird's eye view of what's available than the top level doc pages on erlang.org, e.g., http://www.erlang.org/doc/.

If it's a bitbucket-only thing, what's the initiative that causes it to be on bitbucket? Does bitbucket host developer documentation or some such? I couldn't google up a reference to any such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bit bucket erlang docs have fascinated me too. However, the original docs are here: **http://www.erlang.org/doc/**. The whole documentation is found here: **http://www.erlang.org/doc.html**.

The one at bit bucket seems its their own arrangement similar to **[python 3.2.1 docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/index.html)**. Its the same copy as the original, just in a better arrangement (perhaps), to them. Everything is accessible and its a better guide to some one who is just starting with the language. I like their arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

It's a copy of the Erlang documentation for version R13B02 (a quite old and outdated version). It seems to be compiled with PyDoc.

There are today two good sources for Erlang documentation:

- http://www.erlang.org/doc - This one is always the most up to date
- http://erldocs.com - Easier to search, but doesn't have the user guides

Comment: I'm aware of the erlang.org doc pages (linked one of those in my question), but the arrangement on bitbucket is just much better in my mind. It's impossible to get the scope of what's available from any single page on erlang.org, as far as I can tell.